# Applying handbrake when car is barely rolling

Tags: transmission, damage, handbrake

I am a new driver and at a parking booth, I was trying to get a ticket.
The car started to roll a little bit and my fellow passenger applied the automatic handbrake abruptly.

Can this cause any potential damage to the car?
It is a 4WD vehicle with an auto/electronic hand brake.

Thanks

Comment: Does the vehicle have an automatic or a manual transmission? What is the "automatic handbrake?" Did the passenger move the shift lever, or do something else?

Comment: It has an automatic transmission. I meant a button/electronic handbrake. The passenger pressed the button of the electronic handbrake. Thanks !

Comment: So was the drive engaged? Was the passenger your driving instructor?

Comment: Yes drive was engaged, no the passenger was a relative.

Answer (score 5):

> Can this cause any potential damage to the car?

Almost certainly not. This is exactly what the hand brake (AKA the parking brake) is useful for. The brake stopped the car just as it was intended to.

> It is a 4WD vehicle with an auto/electronic hand brake.

This makes me every more convinced that your car is fine: the car's computer controls the electronic hand brake in a much more controlled manner than the old style "rip it" hand brakes. Worst case, you've slightly used up some of your replaceable parking brake material while using it for its intended purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It seems very unlikely to me that any damage would have occurred from this.